# Sort query results by the most number without repetition

Tags: php, mysql

i have Mysql table Contain fields (ip,postid)

like :

```
ip | postid
x.x| 1
x.x| 2
x.x| 2
x.x| 3
x.x| 4
x.x| 2
x.x| 1
```

i want Sort my query results by the most number of postid without repetition

```
SELECT * FROM table order by count(postid) desc LIMIT 4
```

Results should be,  postid(2|1|3|4)

To obtain the count each postid ,(postid 2 [3] ,postid 1 [2] , Etc.)

Comment: There is no documentation explaining the usage of COUNT(*) which would fail to address this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
select 
postid, 
count(postid) as tot 
from test
group by postid
order by tot
desc
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec13c/2)

Comment: Why this answer is downvoted ? @downvoters you should leave a reason also

Comment: ha down-vote !! well a reason would be nice to know !!

Comment: (+1) You don't deserve a downvote. ;-) I guess, downvoter is jealous.

Comment: @o6qr when you accept the answer make sure you accept correct answer who gave before me. Since it will be unfair for previous answers as they all are correct.

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty, Excellent, this is what I want to do exactly 
Thank you brother :)

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty,Do not worry, I'm doing my first experimenting with all the solutions, and then choose a good 100% correct answer, and she was your answer already

Answer (score 1):

When you want it to be ordered you must use group by and order by:

```
SELECT id,count(*) As `nr` FROM table GROUP BY postid ORDER BY nr DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

use GROUP BY

```
SELECT postid,count(postid) FROM table GROUP BY  postid order by count(postid) desc LIMIT 4
```

Comment: @samitha | Good, but I also want to arrange the results by the most number

Comment: `order by count(postid) ASC LIMIT 4`

Comment: yeah , [order by count(threadid) desc] now works good thnx alot .. another person put also correct answer befor you fix your code and i has been chosen his answer already, do you forgive me for that?